# Wordpress JSON API Extend to Create Users

Tags: api, plugin-json-api

I have the JSON API Plugin installed on my wordpress blog and it works like a charm. However  there is one functionality that i really need.

A method called `create_user` which should take parameters like name, email and password and create new user on the wordpress installation if everything goes correct.

Can someone please help post the code to extended this functionality for the JSON API plugin.